# Requisição ajax em um aplicativo do Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Eu estava desenvolvendo um aplicativo no Chrome e precisava usar a api do Instagram para exibir umas fotos mas quando fui fazer os testes apareceu o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que achei estranho pois o aplicativo tem permissão especial no site:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já faz um tempo que eu convivo com esse erro, já procurei no Google, questões relacionadas e não descobri como fazer uma requisição ajax de um site externo em um *Hosted app* no Chrome.

Curiosidade: Essa mesma requisição funciona em uma extensão normal no navegador mas em um app acontece esse erro.

**Help-me!**

Comment: Consegue colocar um [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.org/) no ar simulando o problema? Com certeza é um problema de [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Acho que você está tentando rodar um arquivo local no Chrome (sem publicar em um App Server da vida), provavelmente precisa de `--allow-file-access-from-files`.

Comment: No jsfiddle vai funcionar normalmente, só no Chrome da esse erro.

Comment: Tenta passar o `--allow-file-access-from-files` então. Quase certeza que o problema é esse.

Comment: Mas e se eu for publicar esse app, todo mundo vai ter que fazer isso? '-'

Comment: Quando você publicar o App ele não vai fazer ajax de arquivos locais... Certo?

Comment: arquivos externos, na api do Instagram..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma Chrome App é mais protegida do que uma extensão. O Google vive melhorando o SDK das Chrome Apps, mas da última (e única) vez que eu tentei fazer uma App para testar, não era permitido acessar URLs externas (CORS). A [documentação](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy#what) parece ainda dizer isso.